# Is it possible to move and click the mouse in an inactive window with Python?

Tags: python, windows, window, mouse, move

Is there a way to make the mouse move to certain coordinates and click inside of a window that might be in the background or behind another window without losing focus.

The idea is to let it work in the background while I'm using the computer for something else.

I'm working with Python on Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check your tags. It is not clear on what operating system you are working on.

Comment: Oh yeah I'll fix that, it's on windows and python.

Comment: Okay then please edit your question. Otherwise we have to downvote it :(